# Leaflet Map v1.7.1 not displaying but markers work

Tags: leaflet

I'm just trying to do a simple map using the Leaflet.js libraries directly instead of the python wrappers(ipyleaflet, folium) but I can't any map to display regardless of what I do.  the map area is drawn the correct size with the zoom controls, as are the tile attributions, and a marker in the right location.  I have tried multiple browsers and also in QWebEngineView as well as  different tile sets.  I've also tried both the hosted js and css scripts as well as local copies The results are the same.  Everything with the same v1.7.1 release though.

Here is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet.css" />
    <script src="leaflet.js"></script>

    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin="" />
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA==" crossorigin=""></script>
    -->
    <style>
        #map {
            width: 900px;
            height: 400px;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
        var layer = L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
            maxZoom: 18,
            id: 'mapbox/satellite-v9',
            tileSize: 512,
            zoomOffset: -1,
            accessToken: 'your.mapbox.access.token'
        });

        var mymap = L.map('map', { preferCanvas: true, center: [43.08695, -73.75792], layers: [layer], zoom: 10 });

        var mymarker = L.marker([43.08695, -73.75792], { draggable: true }).addTo(mymap)

    </script>

  

</body>
</html
```

[Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZKTF.png)

Anybody got any ideas?  This ought to be something really simple...

Comment: Did you set your mapbox access token in L.tileLayer?
`L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}'` I set it up here, changed the tile layer to a non-mapbox one,  uncommented the css cdn and it worked: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-wp35gp?file=index.js

Comment: I see everything working exactly as expected in your project but when I download these files and load index.html directly or from my project in VS2019...the page has zero content, no indication that the map object exists...So I am a totally noob to js and any web stuff...python and C++ are my background...I'm probably doing something really bonehead...

Comment: Ok I got it running by commenting out the import command in the index.js file